# Primefaces Spinner as parameter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to show a list of entries.

A DetailedEntry has a List of entry and an Entry has a number.

The number of each entry should be updateable.

So I created a form for each entry with a spinner in it.

My problem now is that the new number is not saved in the entry.

So I tried to get is as a request parameter which does not work as well?

Does anyone know how to solve it? Or a best practice?

```
<p:dataList var="uiDetailedEntry"
                value="#{entryBacking.updatedEntries}" type="definition">        
       <ui:repeat var="entry" value="#{uiDetailedEntry.entries}">
          <h:form>
              <p:outputLabel value="#{entry.description}" />
              <p:spinner id="newNumber" value="#{entry.number}" min="0" max="30"/>
              <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['ui.button.save']}" action="{entryBacking.saveEntry(entry)}"/>
          </h:form>
        </ui:repeat>
</dataList>
```

BackingBean:

```
public List<UIDetailedEntry> getUpdatedEntries(){
     uiDetailedEntries = getEntriesFromDatabase();
     return uiDetailedEntries ;
    }

public void saveEntry(Entry entry){

        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        int newNumber = Integer.valueOf(ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("newNumber"));
        entry.setNumber(newNumber);
        entryService.save(entry);
}
```

I also tried without request parameter like this but entry never has the new value

```
public void saveEntry(Entry entry){
    entryService.save(entry);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please paste you Entry class too.

Comment: And please provide more information about the statement "the new number is not saved in the entry". Is the method `saveEntry` called? How do you know that the value is not saved? Do you check it in database?

Comment: This question helped me to answer my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376514/catching-primefacess-spinner-value-inside-repeat-structure